# Apache URL Rewrite How To

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have never gotten into regex stuff or apache rewrite stuff but I've done a big ecommerce site for a customer and he's just now asking me if I can do URL rewrites for his store. I have 2 that I need and it would be of great help if someone could tell me if it is even possible to rewrite how he wants it.

The product details URL is currently:
product/details/3/royal-blue-choir-stole

And he wants it to just be...
/royal-blue-choir-stole

And the second one is the category pages. They are currently

category/view/choir-stoles

and he wants them to just be
/choir-stoles

Is this possible? The full url to the site is currently http://www.stoles.com/stoles (username alex, password superman) if you want to take a look at what's currently done. Its programmed in codeigniter.

Currently it has the following rewrites to get rid of the index.php in the codeigniter URL's...

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

Comment: would be useful to know what the current rewrites are

Comment: edited the question with the current rewrites.

Answer (score 0):

in first there should be different between category url and  product details url , maybe like this :

```
product details  :   pd/royal-blue-choir-stole    
category         :   /choir-stoles
```

but if you want to do without prefix so you can match the url with you product title or category name . for example :
you have a category with name "Choir Stoles" and product as name "royal blue choir stole" .
now you can use these lines of code in your htaccess :

```
RewriteRule /([a-z\-]+)$ router.php?q=$1  [NC,L]
```

then you can get $_GET['q'] in router.php and with replacing "-" with space , search in database and find out is it category or a product and get that's information form database .
hope that helpful.

Answer (score 0):

for product url (add in routes.php) (product/details/blah-blah-blah-blah)

change the value in routes to

```
$route['product/:any'] = "product/details";
product ->controller
details -> action
```

for category url  (category/view/blah-blah)

```
$route['catagory/:any'] = "catagory/details";
    catagory ->controller
    details -> action
```

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html

Answer (score 0):

this is something i'm really interested in. if you have a limited number of categories that are not going to change often, then it seems reasonable to hard code the category routes.

```
 $route['choir-stoles'] = "shop/choir-stoles";
```

otherwise, if the categories are ever changing, or if you want to do the products the same way, then you will have to do a search on whatever value is in the url - which could be anything. so then what i'm wondering -- what kind of prefiltering could happen so if you get a request like

```
 http://www.stoles.com/213as+dfjljWHATEVER
```

that its stopped before going to the database and controller.

**Should this type of filtering happen in Routes?** and should we be logging these kind of attempts? banning the IP if they do it a few times in a row? or is this overly paranoid and its not a concern?

right now the style is to push the search value behind one word like 'product', 'category', etc but more clients are going to ask for short urls, it would be cool to come up with some best practices.

Comment: isn't it possible with an apache mod rewrite to just drop the first 2 uri segments?